# How can I get the width of the browser in pixels using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the width of an `<iframe>` based on the browser's width and height.

Is it possible to get the browser's width in pixels using JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using :

```
$(window).width();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use jQuery, to determine the actual size of the browser window, use the following properties:

in Internet Explorer (quirks mode):

```
document.body.offsetWidth
```

in Internet Explorer < 9 (standards mode):

```
document.documentElement.offsetWidth
```

in most other browsers:

```
window.innerWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
 var objlast = document.getElementById('lastdiv');

 if (objlast.offsetParent) {
            do {
                  curleftLast += objlast.offsetLeft;
                  curtopLast += objlast.offsetTop;
            } while (objlast = objlast.offsetParent);
      }

    document.getElementById('iframe').style.height = curtopLast+"px";
```

this will also work, and **lastdiv** would be the endpoint of your window from where you want to fetch window height.

Thanks.